# Nginx: proxy graphs from remote munin server

Tags: nginx, munin

I'm trying to create, under a series of nginx hosted domains, a /graphs folder (so I'm trying to use proxy...) at which graphs from a remote munin server would be shown.

The munin server is graphing several domain servers as external nodes, and works good... (I have set it up in a dedicated nginx server and uses CGI)
Now I would like to let final domain users to monitor their "portion" of the munin graphs tree.

I have being using:

```
location /graphs/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host my-graphs-server.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://my-graphs-server.example.com./munin/clients/Servers/client1/;
}
```

This way, I can reach the targeted munin server html site, but I got no images, no css... unusable...

Munin generated code is full of ../ ../.. ../../.. so I guess there shoud be a way to rewrite base path, manually target munin /static folder and so...
I find nginx proxy + rewrite very dense...

Has anyone achieved proxying a munin server?